# Displaying feature points from an imported csv file (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv, import, display

I have imported the following CSV file into GEE (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14XYsKQYylJ77uhNVhiLqUYwyGgBhE0N1h4F5QTn2Cvk/edit#gid=832877374).
However, even though I can print the data, I wasn't able to display it using the usual procedure. (No error Messages)

Asset: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/farhatlokmen/ecoModeling/Falco

Code: (https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Ffarhatlokmen%2Ftrials%3Atest)

```
var falcoCherrug = ee.FeatureCollection("users/farhatlokmen/ecoModeling/Falco");

print(falcoCherrug);
Map.addLayer(falcoCherrug.draw({color: 'ff0000', pointRadius: 5}), {}, 'Falco Cherrug');
```

Comment: You have to provide more details. For starters, what error message do you get when doing this? If you want someone else to test this, you also have to share your `users/farhatlokmen/Falco` asset.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have edited my question accordingly. There is no error message.

Comment: The import of the CSV file geometries must have failed: https://code.earthengine.google.com/1b4d89f791e3cc3fed8982c5e822889e
Look in the console - all geometries have 0 vertices.

Comment: Would it be possible to show me by screenshots a simple example of importing a CSV file that has longitude and latitude columns?

Comment: You have the docs here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/importing#upload-a-csv-file

Comment: Thank you! I have solved the issue by going into advanced options and specifying the lon and lat columns manually.

Comment: Excellent! Mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this issue, I went to the advanced options and specified the lon and lat columns manually.